Adding Resistor to Match Power Draw for Fan Replacement
I'm replacing a 12V 0.23A fan with a 12V 0.06A fan and want to keep the power draw the same. I believe there is load-sensing at the power supply side, which detects lower draw and shuts down due presumed fan-failure.
Tacho/PWM monitoring is not in effect, it's only using 2-leads for fan connectors.
How do I calculate and add the appropriate resistor?
I ran circuit simulation at falstad.com, which showed me that I will need to add a parallel resistor with the new fan to maintain same power draw. Are my presumptions correct? (I simulated new fan as a 200Ω resistor and old fan as 52.2Ω resistor, which using Ohm's law should correlate to their 0.06A and 0.23A typical input current from their specifications)
How would I go about this, order any 70Ω resistor rated for 3W+ and solder between GND and +12V line of the new fan? Would orientation of the resistor matter?

See if you need it first. Current sensing seems a bit much for fan failure detection. Try to avoid adding a heater whenever possible.

Yes, I do. I wouldn't mention load sensing and shut down otherwise.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@jackar - Hi, FYI the above canned comment from "Community" means the person who reviewed the question on the First Questions queue, felt that it would be improved if you added additional details. Although it seems clear what you are asking, IMHO there is a real risk that why you are asking is because of an XY-problem. Personally I haven't seen current monitoring of fans, to detect operation. Are you familiar with the usual tacho monitoring method? I have seen fan substitutions fail due to lack of PWM functionality too. || Do you want to provide more details of fans & system for review?

Tacho/PWN monitoring is not in effect, it's only using 2-leads for fan connectors.

”I believe there is load-sensing at the power supply side” Unlikely, but possible. Does the tacho output match for both fans? Sensing current costs money. Tacho is almost free.

@winny - "Does the tacho output match for both fans?" OP reports there that there isn't a tacho output. They commented: "Tacho/PWN monitoring is not in effect, it's only using 2-leads for fan connectors". I'll copy that important info into the question.

@SamGibson Oh! An outlier. Older design?

@winny - I'm as surprised as you... Older design (pre-tacho output fans) could make sense, yes. But it makes the design "fragile" doesn't it e.g. it means the equipment manufacturer (whoever they are) relies on only buying fans with a specific power from their supplier. If those are out of stock and different power fans are available, what do they do?! || I have a vague memory that some piece of equipment monitored fans by the little current pulses on their power rail (so seized rotor = no current pulses), but it's too long ago for me to remember details. Does it sound familiar?

I know...Maxim(?) has a few fan control chips that look for commutation pulses. It could be set for more poles than the replacement fan.

These 0.23A fans are ubiquitous. Perhaps they decided cheaping out on fans w/o tacho would be more economical than having to splurge on draw-sensing fan controller.

@vir - Interesting, thanks, so perhaps I'm not completely imagining that such devices do/did exist. I did design-in some Maxim devices long ago and would have been more familiar with their products then, so perhaps that could be what I'm (vaguely) remembering. I did a quick search now of the (ex-)Maxim devices and found various fan controllers, but I couldn't find one that measured fan speed by the commutation pulses (shrug). || As you said, if the number of commutation pulses changed between fans, and those were detected by the fan controller, it could be a problem for fan substitutions...

@SamGibson The chip I was thinking about was the Microchip TC642, but Maxim does make a fan failure detector that uses the same principle: MAX6684.

@vir - Very useful, thanks for that info.

Your calculations are correct:
If you want to draw the difference in specified currents between the two fans (0.23 - 0.06 =) 0.17 A at 12 V then the resistor should be approximately 70 Ω. And it would dissipate (0.17² x 70 =) 2 W. Your suggestion of using a 70 Ω, 3 W (or greater) resistor is appropriate i.e. a 50% power margin.
Depending on the space you have available, parts availability etc. there are various physical options. Don't use a 2 W resistor, running at 100% of its rating. And, of course, whatever is near that resistor is going to get hot too e.g. by radiated & conducted heat.
The electrical orientation of the resistor doesn't matter (I assume you're asking whether the two connections on the resistor are functionally identical; the physical orientation might matter, if you're trying to minimise the effects of its heat on nearby things).
As mentioned in the comment above by vir, you are effectively adding a 2 W heater. To avoid that, it may be worth investigating & reverse-engineering the current sense circuit (assuming this is what is detecting the difference between the fan currents, as you believe) to see if it can be tuned to accept the lower current of the replacement fan, rather than adding the resistor.
I'm still surprised that a fan seems to be monitored by its current draw...
